# Boolean rings, subring of the ring its elements come from?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $B=\{x \in C:x=x^2\}$ then is the boolean ring $B$ a subring of the ring $C$?

Answer (score 1):

For most rings $C$, the $B$ you defined will not be closed under addition and will therefore not be a ring at all.  Consider, for example, what happens when $C$ is the ring of integers.

Comment: What about the ring of integers modulo 2?

Comment: @Jenny If, by great good fortune, your $C$ happens to be the ring of integers modulo 2, then $B=C$ and $B$ is, indeed, a subring of itself.